# Gray the card on click in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

A common function in infinite list is that, the item will be grayed after when we clicked on him. Can we get this effect with only HTML, CSS, JS, jQuery(on the user's side)?

How it works?

1.) the user clicks on the card element
[image]
2.) When pressed, class `text-muted` is added to the card element, causing it to be grayed out as below
[image]

The simplest example of code in bootarap looks like this:

```
  {% for obj in objects %}
  <a href="/detail/id/" target="_blank">
    <div class="card" id="card{{ obj.id }}">
      <!--..content card..-->
    </div>
  </a>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem, you said the solution on event click add class.

Comment: The class will be added and changed, but reloading the page forgets this class, and again we only have the initial status in all cards

Comment: The only way is use `localStorage` and store id of card need to be gray, then on load page add class to element into `localStorage`.

Comment: You just can add css styles to visited links `a:visited { color: grey; }`

Comment: @VitaliyRayets true, mine wasn't the only way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can add CSS pseudo-class to visited links `a:visited { color: grey; }`. Without custom class and javascript logic.
See [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)

Comment: Simple and fast, that's what I needed. Thank you!